# Equivalence between two ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, equivalence-relations

I have formulated a function $f(x)$ as the solution to an ordinary differential equation

$$
f'(x) = \phi(f(x),x) \\
f(x_0) = f_0.
$$

and also the function $F(x) = \int_0^x f(s)ds$ as

$$
F'(x) = \Phi(F(x),x) \\
F(x_0) = F_0.
$$

Is it possible, in general, to prove that the two formulations are equivalent (for differentiable functions)?

Comment: How $\phi(f(x), x)$ is related to $\Phi(F(x), x)$?

Comment: @Bob That is my main question. I have so far shown this is the case for a specific scenario, but I am wondering if this can be generalized to the equivalence of the two formulations, under some conditions.

Comment: You must have $f(x_0) = \Phi(F_0, x_0) = f_0$, and $\Phi(F(x), x) = f(x)$, how that can be useful?

Comment: @Bob I think your comment together with the, properly corrected, answer by Abezhiko is what I am looking for. Basically, your comments links $\Phi$ with the solution, but I wanted to link $\Phi$ and $\phi$. The only problem is that Abezhiko's answer has several errors in the arguments of these functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you have to consider the functions $\phi(x,y)$ and $\Phi(x,y)$ as bivariate, such that
$$
\phi(x,f(x)) = f'(x) = F''(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Phi(x,F(x)) = \Phi_x(x,F(x))+\Phi_y(x,F(x))f(x),
$$
where the indices on $\Phi$ denote partial derivatives, with the boundary condition $\Phi(x_0,F_0) = f_0$. Recalling that $f(x) = \Phi(x,F(x))$ and setting $y = F(x)$, one gets the following partial differential equation :
$$
\Phi_x(x,y) + \Phi_y(x,y)\Phi(x,y) = \phi(x,\Phi(x,y))
$$
which is a very complicated problem in general, because of its non-linearity and the composition on the right-hand side.

Comment: In your notation, do you mean $\Phi$ as a function of $x$ and $F$, or are you changing the dependence to $x$ and $f$?

Comment: @SnoopDogg   Sorry, I made a mistake, I'll edit.

Comment: @SnoopDogg  Actually, it is possible to "clean/ameliorate" the relation between $\phi$ and $\Phi$ by removing the occurrences of $f$ and $F$. Sorry for the multiple muddled edits.